# Inconsistency of Python plus operator

Tags: python, operators

```
In [26]: l=[]

In [27]: s="asdsad"

In [28]: l+=s

In [29]: l
Out[29]: ['a', 's', 'd', 's', 'a', 'd']
```

However,

```
In [30]: l+s
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/xiaohan/code/proteincrawler/id_crawler.py in <module>()
----> 1 
      2 
      3 
      4 
      5 

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

So, the *+* operators in '+=' and '+' are different.

But I think they should be the same, because they are all *plus*

Am I wrong or something happens behind the scene?

Comment: The only difference that "pop up" from your post is that, in the second plus operator, you didn't assign the result to a variable. That's translate with the operation: print(l+s) and, maybe, this messes up the whole thing. Have you tried yet to assign l+s to a new variable ?

Comment: @DonCallisto Completely wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained [here](http://old.nabble.com/Add-vs-in-place-add-of-str-to-list-td19774277.html). Copied from the link:

> It's because the `+=` operator is doing the equivalent of calling the `extend` method, which treats its argument as a generic sequence, and doesn't enforce type.